# SEO: #!?_escaped_fragment_=

Tags: angularjs, seo, prerender

I've read google documentation about ajax crawling and ?_escaped_fragment_=

I am using prerender.io to cache pages and the application uses AngularJS. However, the cached pages are ending with "http://(...)/about-us/#!?_escaped_fragment_=" instead of just http://(...)/about-us/ , as defined in the sitemap.

I am using the following line to force prerender to wait for the end of ajax calls. When they're finished, I toggle the value.

```
window.prerenderReady = false;
```

I've also configured in the app.js config setting HTML5 and hashprefix, as below:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

Comment: thats normal, imo. google first visit /about-us/ and then access to ?_escaped_fragment_= version, so prerender.io only involve there.

Comment: Can you send me an email so that I can look into this? You shouldn't have URLs that look like `http://(...)/about-us/#!?_escaped_fragment_=` since the #! gets translated to ?_escaped_fragment_=. Having both means something is wrong with the URL when being accessed from us. todd@prerender.io

Comment: I think this happens because someone added the pages incorrectly. When I log in into prerender I saw several URLs with http://(...)/about-us/#!?_escaped_fragment_= . Isn't that supposed to be just http://(...)/about-us/ , accordingly to sitemap? or http://(...)/about-us/#! at least...